# how to get file path in assets for flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to open a pdf file in assets,so I need to get  file path.

Here's my solution, and I had to copy the file because I couldn't get the path.
I think the best solution is to get the file address directly.

```
Future<void> writeToFile(ByteData data, String path) {
    final buffer = data.buffer;
    return new File(path).writeAsBytes(
        buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes));
  }


  Future<File> createFileOfPdfUrl() async {

    final filename = 'test.pdf';
    var bytes = await rootBundle.load("assets/data/test.pdf");

    String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
    writeToFile(bytes,'$dir/$filename');
    File file = new File('$dir/$filename');

    return file;
  }
```

Comment: Is the code not working or do you want to have a different solution? What is your problem exactly?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to work with assets you need to declare the path on your **pubspec.yaml**, as described at [Flutter docs about assets and images](https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images), like so:

```dart
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/
```

And to work with files if depends on your implementation, without knowing more info I can indicate you to follow the [Reading and Writing Oficial Docs](https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files).

Answer (score 0):

You have to uncomment fonts key word also in puspebc.yamel file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).